# ORACLE: What's wrong with my sql? Why it could not give me a sum value after compiling?

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

Here's my sql code, could anyone do me a favor?

```
CREATE VIEW  "UOS_VU_STUDENT_AVERAGE" ("Fullname", "Average score") AS 
  SELECT
G.TITLE_NAME||' '||A.FIRST_NAME||' '||A.LAST_NAME AS "Fullname",
    SUM (C.GRADE)/(SUM(F.CREDITS)/10) AS "Average score"

from
STUDENT A,
COURSE B,
STUDENT_MODULE C,
STUDENT_SESSION D,
STATUS_LOOK_UP E,
MODULE F,
TITLE_LOOK_UP G


where
B.COURSE_TITLE = 'Information Management' AND
D.COURSE_LEVEL = '1' AND
D.STATUS_ID = '1' AND
B.COURSE_ID = A.COURSE_ID AND
A.STUDENT_ID = D.STUDENT_ID AND
D.STUDENT_ID = C.STUDENT_ID AND
D.ACADEMIC_YEAR_ID = C.ACADEMIC_YEAR_ID AND
C.MODULE_CODE = F.MODULE_CODE AND
A.TITLE_ID = G.TITLE_ID

GROUP BY
G.TITLE_NAME,
A.FIRST_NAME,
A.LAST_NAME,
C.GRADE,
C.MODULE_CODE,
F.CREDITS

ORDER BY LAST_NAME
```

Ideally, it should show me just one single line including Mr. David Smith's average score of his name, however what I've got was different.

But what I got was a list of all his grades (scores) in level 1

Not sure where I made it wrong...hope someone could help me. Many thanks.

Comment: Try taking the last three columns out of your Group By.

Comment: STATUS_LOOK_UP is not part of your where clause, are you sure it's needed? You know there's an AVG function in sql right? your group by doesn't seem right too, but I'm at work I can't test your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong `group by` clause.  Remove the column that are in aggregation functions:

```
GROUP BY G.TITLE_NAME, A.FIRST_NAME, A.LAST_NAME
```

And, module code seems totally unnecessary.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! I just tried, it worked and I deleted the unnecessary part.

Comment: @S.P.K If this answer solved your issue, click on the check mark at it left to mark it as accepted.